# How to add buttons programmatically in Java WindowBuilder

Tags: java, windowbuilder

I'm making a game (Mine-Sweeper) for a subject in University.

I'm focusing in the first level, it has 7 rows and 10 columns. So I was thinking to add in some way, to add programmatically the buttons for each square. Because in this case, I need to add 70 buttons (7x10).

[image: First two grey boxes are two buttons...]
This is the code that generates the WindowBuilder editor for the two buttons.

```
// buttons
private JButton button;
private JButton button_1;

public VTableroN1() {   
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 640, 480);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[10%][10%][10%][10%][10%][10%][10%][10%][10%][10%]", "[14.28%][14.28%][14.28%][14.28%][14.28%][14.28%][14.28%]"));
    // buttons 
    frame.getContentPane().add(getButton(), "cell 0 0,grow");
    frame.getContentPane().add(getButton_1(), "cell 1 0,grow");
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

// buttons
private JButton getButton() {
    if (button == null) {
        button = new JButton("");
    }
    return button;
}
private JButton getButton_1() {
    if (button_1 == null) {
        button_1 = new JButton("");
    }
    return button_1;
}
```

My question is, **How do I add in a iterative-way 70 buttons without doing this one by one?**

I guess it's a silly question, but I haven't find a good solution. I couldn't find anything about this in StackOverflow, only similar questions but for Android, but this has nothing to do with that I think.

Thanks in advance, **let me know if you need me to paste more code**. I think I pasted only the relevant code.

Comment: You have 3 options. #1 Dragging a button gives you the freedom to manipulate it using the Window Builder. However, this will require you to create all instances yourself. #2 Alternatively you can use a text generator and create the code accordingly once you know how it should look like. #3 Create the required structures dynamically at runtime (see answer from @rdonuk) I would recommend the last approach here, because you probably won't need to handle a specific button differently from the others, like let's say the Button at position 3/2. But in your scenario i don't think that this holds.

Comment: Yeah I guess the third option is what I was thinking. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete working code is as it follows:

```
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 640, 480);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[10%][10%][10%][10%][10%][10%][10%][10%][10%][10%]", "[14.28%][14.28%][14.28%][14.28%][14.28%][14.28%][14.28%]"));
    frame.setVisible(true);
    for (int row = 0; row<7; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col<10; col++) {
            JButton b = new JButton();
            frame.getContentPane().add(b, "cell "+ col +" "+ row +",grow");
            // click method
            frame.getContentPane().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    // code
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The important thing is

```
for (int row = 0; row<7; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col<10; col++) {
        JButton b = new JButton();
        frame.getContentPane().add(b, "cell "+ col +" "+ row +",grow");
    }
}
```

Comment: Adapted it to rows and cols and works perfect inside my initialize() function! thank you